If $R$ is a finite $A$ module and $S$ is a finite $B$ module, then $R \otimes S$ is a finite $A \otimes B$ module
$A = k[x_1, ..., x_n], B = A = k[y_1, ..., y_m]$
If $R$ is a finite $A$ module and $S$ is a finite $B$ module, why is $R \otimes_k S$ a finite $A \otimes_k B$ module?
$\forall r \in R, r \in Ar_1+...+Ar_p, \forall s \in S, s \in Bs_1+...+Bs_q$,
is it true that $r \otimes s \in \Sigma_{i,j}(A \otimes_k B)(r_i \otimes_k s_j)$? Why?

These are tensor products over what ring?

The equations are wrongly typed so don't hold. An element cannot be a submodule. Anyway, the question can be answered by using the definition of the module structure over $A \otimes B$. Try it.

Explaination
Recall the definition of tensor product. Then assume $r = \sum a_i r_i$, $s = \sum b_j s_j$.
$$
r \otimes s = (\sum_i a_i r_i) \otimes (\sum_j b_j s_j) = \sum_{i,j} (a_i \otimes b_j)  (r_i \otimes s_j)
$$
The last equality comes from the definition of the action of $A\otimes_k B$ on $R \otimes_k S$.
Another proof
There are exact sequences $A^m \longrightarrow R \longrightarrow 0, \tag{1}$ $B^n \longrightarrow S \longrightarrow 0, \tag{2}$ for some finite $m,n \geq 1$.
Then tensoring $A^m$ on the second sequence, we get an exact sequence
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
A^m \otimes_k B^n \longrightarrow A^m \otimes_k S \longrightarrow 0 
\end{equation}
Tensor $S$ on the first sequence, we get an exact sequence
$$
\tag{4}
A^m \otimes_k S \longrightarrow  R \otimes_k S \longrightarrow 0 
$$
Combining (3)(4), we have an exact sequence $A^m \otimes_k B^n \longrightarrow  R \otimes_k S  \longrightarrow 0$.

By the action of $A \otimes_k B$ on $R \otimes_k S$, do you mean we can view the element in $A \otimes_k B$ as a homomorphism on $R \otimes_k S$?

Means we define $R\otimes S$ as an $A \otimes B$ module via $(a \otimes b) \cdot (r \otimes s) = ar \otimes bs$. It is an Abelian group homomorphism.

I see. Thank you!
